# Setting Own Parameters from Database using PDO::FETCH_CLASS

Tags: php, class, pdo

I have created a class user which reflects row in a user table. There is one method populate in which I am fetching values from database based on primary key and try to store it in self object. I can do it by getting all variables and setting them one by one per field. Is there any way to do it using PDO::FETCH_CLASS or any other simple method ?

If I try to store it using $this = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_CLASS ) it gives Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this in /var/www/html/php/classes.php on line 51 error.

I don't want to use ORM style tools and want to develop the class by my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like list($this->a, $this->b, $this->c) = array((...)), where array is (probably) your fetched result?
Because you cannot assignt $this variable, only refernce it's fields and methods.

Another solution is to implement [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/kr/class.arrayaccess.php) interface and store data in underlying array.

Comment: I dont want to assign values one by one. that is too much time consuming.

Comment: Then use ArrayAccess with combination of magic method __get()

Comment: ok.. will keep that in mind. rating your answer +1 and will wait for more answers. I think this question is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453933/setting-an-object-returned-from-pdo-in-its-own-class?rq=1